# How to apply perspective transofrmation to ellipse?

Tags: c++, opencv, transformation, ellipse, perspectivecamera

Having transformation in a matrix, which can be applied to points, how to apply the same transformation to ellipse? Most general parameter `ellipse` function accepts is `RotatedRect`, which is not so general as parameters `getPerspectiveTransform` function accepts. So if I transform rectangle into some quadrilateral, I will be unable to inscribe ellipse to it.

How to accomplish?

Comment: Hi Suzan. Can you provide some graphical examples?

Comment: Are u just trying to draw the transformed ellipse? Or you actually need it for computation? In the former case, you can always draw the ellipse first, and call `perspectivetransform` on the drawn image.